# Xamarin: Get device signal strength and/or battery life cross platform

Tags: c#, android, ios, iphone, xamarin

I know there are ways to obtain the phones signal strength and the battery life using Android specific functions but I want a way to do this cross platform. Is this possible? Or do I need to write this separately for both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Battery interface is included in Xamarin.Forms.Labs toolkit available from NuGet. Link to [Interface definition](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Device/IBattery.cs). A sample usage is found in rendering to abstracted [Xamarin Forms UI](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Sample/Pages/Services/ExtendedDeviceInfoPage.cs). If you don't want to include references to Xamarin.Forms then you can easily pull the source from GitHub and include it to your project.

Network functionality is in the plans to be added in the very near future. You can submit a feature request on GitHub by [clicking here.](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/new)